# If $f(t)/t \to 0$ as $t \to 0,$ is f(0) = 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions

Let $f:[0,T]\to H$ be a map where $H$ is a Hilbert space

If $\frac{f(t)}{t} \to 0$ in $H$ as $t \to 0$, does it follow that $f(0) = 0$?

I multiply by $t$ and take the limit then it givves me the answer, yes, is that right?

Comment: No not necessarily, because the limit does not say anything about the exact value of the function. However you know that $f(t) \to 0$ as $t\to 0$... That is not the same as $f(0)=0$, is it?

Comment: Ur right but if we know it is defined at $t=0$ then it is true

Comment: You probably mean if $f$ is continuous at $t=0$..